# UserDefinedTarget alternative | Vuforia 10.20.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

On version 10.20.3 of Vuforia I can’t find UserDefinedTarget, is there now an alternative to this tool? I looked on the Internet and found nothing. The only thing I could find is that this tool has become obsolete. I tested the target image but it does not have the same functionality as the UDT. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Vuforia Engine's User Defined Targets have been deprecated since version 9.6.3.

You can use their Instant Image Targets instead: https://developer.vuforia.com/library/objects/instant-image-targets
See the section on creating an Image Target from a file at runtime.

Use the method for locally stored images
`createImageTarget(Texture2D texture, float widthInMeters, string targetName)`

See also the [other API methods](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/sites/default/files/references/unity/classVuforia_1_1ObserverFactory.html#a15f254e036bac919dca129987122bfbd) for runtime Image Target creation.

Hope it helps.